# PagedList is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, paging

PagedList is deprecated, what should I use instead? I'm using paging library to fetch the data from firestore.
Here is my code

```
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(2)
        .setPageSize(10)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version `3.0.0` still in alpha (currently `3.0.0-alpha13` ) `PagedList` is deprecated and has been replaced by `PagingData`. [Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data) you could find a detailed documentation about the **paging library v3**

Answer (score 0):

You need to update both paging dependancy along with the Firestore UI dependancy

```
 implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.2.1'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'
```

This is the new way of implementing the PagingConfig. If you don't update dependancies , PagingConfig cannot be added to the FirestorePagingOption as a query.If shows a error

```
 PagingConfig config = new PagingConfig(6,1,false,6,30);
 FirestorePagingOptions<DCRData> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<DCRData>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(act)
                .setQuery(query, config, DCRData.class)
                .build();
```